# Reading a JSON object elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm pretty much new to jquery, i'm trying to read an JSON object.

My Jquery ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var resource = "v1/projects";

        var url = '@Url.Action("Proxy")?resource=' + resource;

        var method = 'GET';


        var settings = {
            dataType: "text",
            type: method,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

               var res= JSON.stringify(data);


               for (var k in res) {
                   alert(res)
               }

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

                alert("error");
            }

        };



        $.ajax(url, settings);
    });
```

Ajax call works fine and i receive the following result.

[image]

I need to extract name and description from the result.

I tried using the for loop but it prints all the elements in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with the following.

```
 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                     var obj = eval("(" + jqXHR.responseText + ")");

                      for (var k in obj.data) {
                        alert(obj.data[k].name);

                      }

                },
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.` operator

```
var res=JSON.parse(data);
$.each(res,function(i,v){
    alert(v.name);
    alert(v.description);
});
```

Comment: i would recommned you to use `dataType: "json",` and return as JSON from server ... that you you don't have to parse or stringify your json

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `JSON.stringify`, you would want to use `var res= JSON.parse(data)` to convert it into a JS object and then use `alert(res[k])` in the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for (var k in res) {
    alert(' name=' +k+ ' description=' +k+');
}
```